# angular controller inline annotation syntax

Tags: angularjs

I have a MyResource service defined like this:

```
angular.module('resourceApp')
  .factory('MyResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/data');
}]);
```

And then I have a controller which uses MyResource as a dependancy:

```
angular.module('resourceApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['MyResource', function($scope, MyResource) {
    $scope.data = MyResource.get(); // <-- this is where the error occurs
}]);
```

When I define the dependancy like above, using an *Inline Array Annotation,* I get an error "MyResource is undefined" at the line marked with the comment.

But if I change the syntax to *Implicit Annotation*:

```
angular.module('resourceApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MyResource) {
    $scope.data = MyResource.get();
});
```

I somehow magically get things working!

The question is: **what's wrong with the first one?** I could leave the implicit annotation, but the documentation says that it won't survive the minification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting the $scope in the first one, it should be:

```
anguar.module('app').controller('CTRL', ['$scope', 'MyService', function($scope, Service)
```

Currently you have no scope, and the $scope variable actually points to the service

Comment: Yes! I tried including '$scope', but put it _after_ 'MyService'! That's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify the $scope in your array:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyResource', function($scope, MyResource) {
```